# AssertionError: relay-101/index.js: getBabelRelayPlugin(): Expected schema to be an object with a `__schema`

Tags: relay

I was following [Relay 101: Building A Hacker News Client](https://medium.com/@clayallsopp/relay-101-building-a-hacker-news-client-bb8b2bdc76e6#.wik8uo48l) Tutorial.

But in the process I got error

```
AssertionError: relay-101/index.js: getBabelRelayPlugin():
Expected schema to be an object with a `__schema` property.
at getSchema (/Users/ruseel/p/spike/relay-101/node_modules/babel-relay-plugin/src/getBabelRelayPlugin.js:224:3)
at NodePath.Plugin.visitor.TaggedTemplateExpression (/Users/ruseel/p/spike/relay-101/node_modules/babel-relay-plugin/src/getBabelRelayPlugin.js:104:26)
...
```

and after little digging (console.log in getBabelRelayPlugin.js) I noticed introspection var in [getBabelRelayPlugin.js](https://github.com/facebook/relay/blob/master/scripts/babel-relay-plugin/src/getBabelRelayPlugin.js#L198)

```
   const introspection = typeof schemaProvider === 'function' ?
    schemaProvider() :
    schemaProvider;
```

is like this.

```
{"errors":[{"message":"Must provide query string."}]}
```

But I have no idea why this is happening?
Why is this error happening?

any direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Now I am trying to compare with final source  https://github.com/clayallsopp/relay-101 with mine.

Answer (score 0):

I made a typo in babelRelayPlugin.js, in**s**trospectionQuery instead of introspectionQuery.

```
var babelRelayPlugin = require('babel-relay-plugin');
var introspectionQuery = require('graphql/utilities').introspectionQuery;
var request = require('sync-request');

var graphqlHubUrl = 'http://www.graphqlhub.com/graphql';
var response = request('GET', graphqlHubUrl, {
  qs: {
    query: introspectionQuery
  }
});
```